# How do i get other objects properties in python

Tags: python, blender

OK i'm in blender and i want to make it where if the player hits an object that has a property of lets say "box" then the game can tell my HUD [Heads up display] scene to add +=1 to its property. 
but i don't want to have to add a lot of logic bricks.
iv tried to to use one collision logic brick to see if i could get its property but it didn't work out.  here's the code i made

```
itemType = cont.sensors['itemType'] 

type = itemType.hitObject

if ['box'] in type:
    print("Box")
```

I tried to print some string to see if it would work but it never would print.

Comment: try removing the square brackets `if 'box' in type:`.

Comment: Please put a `print(type)` before you `if`-statement and let's see the output.

Comment: `type` is a builtin function, you should not replace it.

Comment: it worked i put 
    print(type)
        
    if 'box' in type:
        print("it worked") 
and on the system console it printed " CubePickup" and "it worked"

Comment: oh ok ive changed it to objType

Comment: Now that your code works & your problem is solved, add the solution to this question yourself & then accept it. Or maybe @tMJ should make his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By typing in, `if ['box'] in type:`, your code is basically trying to search for *a list containing a single element `'box'`* in it. i.e, `['box']`.

What you actually want to do is, you want to find the element `'box'` in your list, and hence you should remove the square brackets. `if 'box' in type:`

P.S. Although you can, but it is not a good practice to use the names of built-in functions as variables or redefine them, unless if you want to do that explicitly. You have done so with the bulit-in function `type()`.